# Pointer being freed was not allocated in C++?

Tags: c++

I am making a board game for a class. I pass each move into a node, and if a user presses u I am supposed to undo the board until it gets to the beginning state. If I try to undo the board more than once I get a message (Pointer being freed was not allocated)? Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this error message?

```
state * removeState(state * head, int *board, int boardSize, int move, int score){
    state * newState = (state *)malloc(sizeof(state));
    newState->board = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (boardSize * boardSize));
    if( head->next == NULL) {
        printf("Can't undo past the beginning of the game.  Enter 'c' to continue: ");
        char c;
        scanf(" %c", &c);   // now pause the output

    }
    if(head->next!= NULL){

    newState = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete(newState); // THIS CAUSES THE ERROR MESSEGE IF I UNDO MORE THAN ONCE!


    for( int row=0; row<boardSize; row++) {
        for( int col=0; col<boardSize; col++ ) {
            int current = row*boardSize + col;    // 1-d index corresponding to row & col
            board[current]= head->board[current];
        }
    }

    score = newState->score;
    //move = newState ->move;
    printf("Working! \n");

    }
    return newState;
}
```

Comment: You tag this as `C++`, but all I see is 'C' with a ton of mistakes.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`, `printf` in C++? Why not use the STL for this stuff?

Comment: First, why are you using malloc() in a C++ program?  Not only that, you mixed up malloc() with the C++ `delete` operator.  Take a step back and learn what `std::vector` does.  It will make your problems practically disappear.

Comment: @Ed, even better, use the C++ standard library. (STL was a library produced by SGI that was adapted for the 1998 C++ standard).

Answer (score 1):

If you allocate with `malloc()`, you can only deallocate using `free()`.  So issuing a `delete` on memory allocated with `malloc` is undefined behavior.

Second, whenever you start to deallocate memory conditionally like this:

```
 if(head->next!= NULL){
   newState = head;
   head = head->next;
   delete(newState); //
}
```

I can place a bet that this code will break down at some point.  You are now writing or will write "spaghetti-like" code attempting to figure out when the pointer is deleted, when not to delete it, etc.

Then you do this at the end of the function:

```
return newState;
```

Now, is `newState` valid or not?  You don't know, because you may have deleted the memory it was pointing to.  Then again, you will attempt to write code that does all sorts of contortions that attempts to straighten out this dilemma.

You should minimize or totally eliminate coding like this, and instead use a smart pointer class or some other RAII pointer type that knows when to clean up the memory.

Comment: Also it's not even valid to malloc a `state` if it's not POD, which we don't know from this code.